# How to dynamically change the default checkbox by the current checkbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form generated by the Perl language. I want to customize this form to add css effects, without using the default perl form.
The form works well. I can select each radio button before launching queries. But after validating the form,
the focus of the radio button always returns the default check box, ie Date. I think the problem does not come from Perl but from the way I do it with my javascript function. But I did not find how to dynamically change the check box and select the current check box after the validation of the form ?
Does anyone have an idea?
thank you in advance

Here is my html (html 5) script :

```
print '<form name="newForm">';
print '<div>';
print '<input type="radio" name="sort" id="rdo-1" value="up2date" checked>';
print '<label for="rdo-1"><span>Date</span></label>';
print '</div>';
print '<div>';
print '<input type="radio" name="sort" id="rdo-2" value="title" >';
print '<label for="rdo-2"><span>Title</span></label>';
print '</div>';
print '<div>';
print '<input type="radio" name="sort" id="rdo-3" value="author">';
print '<label for="rdo-3"><span>Author</span></label>';
print '</div>';
print '<button type="submit" style="margin-right: 15px;" onClick="sorting()">Sort</button>';
print '</form>';
print "<br />\n";
```

Here is my Javascript :

```
function sorting() {
    if (document.getElementById("rdo-1").checked){
        document.getElementById("newForm").submit();
        document.getElementById("rdo-1").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("rdo-1").focus();
    } else if (document.getElementById("rdo-2").checked){
        document.getElementById("newForm").submit();
        document.getElementById("rdo-2").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("rdo-2").focus();   
    } else {
        document.getElementById("newForm").submit();
        document.getElementById("rdo-3").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("rdo-3").focus();   
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you setting `checked = true` if thats the condition in the first place?

Comment: Would you mind using an id on your form?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldnt use inline event handlers. Second, you are submitting the form multiple times. Just by clicking the submit button, the browser will submit the form. Then, in your JavaScript, you are re-submitting the form (why?). Third, maybe your onclick gets fired after the form is submitted. Use jQuery and the submit event:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('form[name="newForm"]').submit(function() {
      var rdoOne = $('#rdo-1'),
          rdoTwo = $('#rdo-2'),
          rdoThree = $('#rdo-3');

      if (rdoOne.is(':checked')) {
        rdoOne.focus();
      }
      else if (rdoTwo.is(':checked')) {
        rdoTwo.focus();
      }
      else if (rdoThree.is(':checked')) {
        rdoThree.focus();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hello,
I have this script because I tried several solutions already but it does not work. I just tested your solution, but it does not work either. It always returns to the initial checkbox ; knowing that I put the jquery script in an external file.

Comment: In addition, I modified the input like this without success.
print '<button type = "submit" style = "margin-right: 15px;" value = "Submit"> Order </ button> ';

Comment: what do you mean by "return"?

Comment: I mean that the initial checkbox, ie "Date" is always selected, after the validation of the form, but not the current check box. For example, if I click on the radio button "Title" after the validation of the form, it is the radio button "Date" which is selected and not "Title".

Comment: @Tony92 but does the page reload after your submit? what you say makes no sense

Comment: My problem is that the focus always remains on the initial radio button, ie "Date". To answer your question, the page does not load

Comment: @Tony92 please just make a fiddle :)

Comment: ive read that, but its still not clear what your question is. please make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by setting conditions with the *print* command, because I think the command line **print '... checked**   fixes the checked and does not lose to modify it and write it back on the other lines. If anyone has a better idea, I'd love to know him. Thanks again for the help.
My new script is below:

```
print "<form name='newForm'>\n";
    my $mySort = '';
    $mySort = $cgi->param("sort");
    if ($mySort eq "title"){
      print "<input type='radio' name='sort' id='rdo-1' value='up2date'>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-1'><span>Date</span></label>\n";
      print "<input type='radio' name='sort' id='rdo-2' value='title' checked>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-2'><span>Title</span></label>\n";
      print "<input type='radio' name='sort' id='rdo-3' value='author'>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-3'><span>Author</span></label>\n";
    }elsif ($mySort eq "Author"){
      print "<input type='radio' name='sort' id='rdo-1' value='up2date'>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-1'><span>Date</span></label>\n";
      print "<input type='radio' name='sort' id='rdo-2' value='title'>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-2'><span>title</span></label>\n";
      print "<input type='radio' name='sort' id='rdo-3' value='Author' checked>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-3'><span>Author</span></label>\n";

    } else {
      print "<input type='radio' name='tri' id='rdo-1' value='up2date' checked>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-1'><span>Date</span></label>\n";
      print "<input type='radio' name='tri' id='rdo-2' value='title'>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-2'><span>title</span></label>\n";
      print "<input type='radio' name='tri' id='rdo-3' value='Author'>\n";
      print "<label for='rdo-3'><span>Author</span></label>\n";
    }
    print '<button type="submit" style="margin-right: 15px;" value="Submit">Sort</button>';
    print "</form>\n";
    print "<br />\n";
```